# Add Character on date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

If today's date is greater than 10, then it will show like this:

- Today = 20170611
- Result = 20170710M1231

I tried this

```
CASE 
   WHEN (SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112), 4, 2)) > 10 
      THEN (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, (SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112), 1, 6)))) + '10M1231'
      ELSE ''
END AS FREQUENCY
```

but I couldn't get the desired answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were adding the month after spliting the date,this should work

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) > 10 
THEN (SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()),112),1,6))+'10M1231' 
ELSE '' END AS FREQUENCY
```